# Update method in html form in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to update inputs using html form in laravel:

```
 <form  action="{!! route('users.update',['id' => $users->id]) !!}" method="post">

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">customer_name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input  value="{{$name}}" class="form-control form-control-lg"  placeholder="col-form-label-lg">
                </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  > Edit</button>


            </form>
```

Everything in the controller work perfectly however in the view page I received this error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> No message

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your route file

Comment: You need to add `csrf_token`   `{!! csrf_field() !!}`

Comment: i added it but still the same error @Exterminator

Comment: Your route file please

Comment: Route::resource('users','userscontroller'); 
I'm using route resource @Exterminator

Comment: I CHANGED THE METHOD TO PUT AND PATCH BUT IT DOESN'T UPDATE AND SHOWS AN EMPTY PAGE

Comment: you don't have to change the method you need to spoof it like i showed in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your route as `POST` like:

```
Route::post('update/{id}', 'YourController@update')->name('users.update');
```

Comment: i'm using route resource 
i added the route you gave to me 
it doesn't show error but it doesn't update @Saurabh Dhariwal

Comment: @hala: I just give you example.

Comment: @hala: Please check your route using `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @hala: Please add `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">` in your blade file and please check

Comment: @hala: please check your route is POST or PATCH in route file or check in `php artisan route:list`

Comment: it's POST
this is the update row in the route list
 POST      | update/{id}       | users.update  | App\Http\Controllers\userscontroller@update  | web

Comment: @hala: Please change your form method in your blade file like `<form  action="{{ route('users.update',['id' => $users->id]) }}" method="post">
`

Answer (score 0):

You need to spoof the method as you are using to post the data. Since HTML forms can't make `PUT, PATCH, or DELETE` requests, you will need to add a hidden _method field to spoof these HTTP verbs. The @method Blade directive can create this field for you like this:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT') //add this to your form
</form>
```

or

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
        {{ method_field('patch')}} //add this to your form
</form>
```

Comment: <form action="{{ route('users.update',['id' => $users->id]) }}" method="POST">
 @method('PUT') //add this to your form
                        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
                    csrf_token {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">customer_name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input  value="{{$name}}" class="form-control form-control-lg"  placeholder="col-form-label-lg">
     </div>

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `@csrf` and `@method('PATCH')` inside your form view.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I had it worked after adding some lines in my code:

1. Just use `$users->id` instead of doing it as array `['id' => $users->id]`
2. Use `csrf` and spoof the method by adding `@method('PUT')`

Your code should look like this:

```
<form  action="{!! route('users.update', $users->id) !!}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <!--Some fields-->
    @method('PUT')
</form>
```